# CSS grid layout with span and *ngFor number of columns

Tags: html, css, angular, css-grid, ngfor

I'm currently attempting to make a CSS grid with a dynamic number of columns for an Angular app. Part of the grid should be divided into 1-to-n columns, depending on how many items are in a particular array. Each section should have a header as well, with the header for the dynamic section spanning all n columns.
So, for an html page like this:

```
<div class="my-grid"
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="header">Foo</div>
    <div class="cell-D" otherAttributes="otherValues"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="header">Foo</div>
    <div class="cell-E" *ngFor="let object of objects" otherAttributes="otherValues">
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="header">Foo</div>
    <div class="cell-F" otherAttributes="otherValues"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...the result should look something like this:

```
One object in objects:
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| D | E | F |
+---+---+---+

Two objects in objects:
+---+-------+---+
| A |   B   | C |
+---+---+---+---+
| D | E | E | F |
+---+---+---+---+

Three objects in objects:
+---+-----------+---+
| A |     B     | C |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| D | E | E | E | F |
+---+---+---+---+---+

etc.
```

...where A, B, and C are the headers, and D, E, and F correspond to their classes above.

Using `repeat` for a grid-template requires a set number of columns, and setting it to `auto` just makes all the columns stack vertically. Setting it to the maximum possible width leaves blank spaces if there aren't that many columns. I have tried using a subgrid *within* cell E to contain the columns, but the results were the same.
Is there a way I can get the CSS grid-template to allow for varying numbers of columns based on `*ngFor`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 900px;
  min-width: max-content;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-grid>* {
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dynamic {
  display: flex;
}

.dynamic>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="A">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="C">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="D">
    D
  </div>
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div>E</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="F">
    F
  </div>
</div>
```

What I did here is customize the grid's `columns`. Setting `grid-template-columns` with specific dimensions for the first and last cell, then use `1fr` for the middle part to allow it to stretch to accommodate the content's width should replicate the behavior you're looking for.